# HSQLDB databases in SQL clients

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I have a memory HSQLDB database with this connection URL:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test_database
```

It runs fine with my application but I need to configure this database in a SQL Client.

I can't because every clients complain that no host was found or there's no database.

I'm not sure if I'm filling all the information correctly in "host" and "database" fields or if it is a HSQLDB memory restriction.

Has anyone got the same error?? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `:mem:` you define a database which is only accessible within the running java vm. This database resides in memory and cannot be accessed externally via host/port jdbc access.

Please read:

- [Running and Using Hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N10148)
- [Advanced Topics](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html)

Comment: Understood. But if I use to store the database instead of saving it in memory would I have access to it via an SQL Client?

Comment: @Adriano'Stanley' yes. You have to start a server that uses/accesses/serves the stored database. Then you can use a client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Database Manager](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_access_tools) provided by HSQLDB, just run in console

`java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing`

and connect to the jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test_database

Comment: The problem is that I have to merge two databases. One is created dinamically when application runs and the other is a MySQL database. I have to synchronize this tables and fields.